# How to say "short, sweet, to the point" in one word?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a single ᴀᴅᴊᴇᴄᴛɪᴠᴇ to denote *short, sweet, to the point*?

I am thinking of [*poignant*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poignant) but I'm not sure that it connotes elegance/brevity, which is an important aspect of the meaning I would like to convey.

Comment: Please add a sample sentence where you would use the word you are looking for.

Comment: There might be some semantic overlap in some contexts, but *poignant* essentially means *evoking a keen sense of sadness or regret*. On the other hand, *short and sweet* is an idiomatic standard for *brief but pleasant or relevant* (so adding *to the point* is almost redundant, since it's implicit in the preceding words anyway).

Comment: Use 'succinct'.

Comment: *Concise* comes close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the word you are looking for is [succinct:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/succinct)

> adjective
>
> 1. expressed in few words; concise; terse.
> 2. characterized by conciseness or verbal brevity.
> 3. compressed into a small area, scope, or compass

Or possibly [concise:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/concise)

> adjective
>
> 1. expressing or covering much in few words; brief in form but comprehensive in scope; succinct; terse:

Answer (score 10):

While I like *succinct*, if you're looking for a word with a little more [affect](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/affect?s=t) you could try [*pithy*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pithy):

> **pithy** *adj*
>   brief, forceful, and meaningful in expression; full of vigor, substance, or meaning; terse; forcible: *a pithy observation*

Note the "full of vigor" aspect. Where *succinct* merely suggests brevity, *pithy* adds power and resonance into the mix.

Comment: it's a good word.  too bad it kinda sounds like *pity*

Comment: Not really, unless you can't pronounce the *th* digraph. And don't forget what Twain said: "The difference between the right word and almost the right word is the difference between lightning and a lightning bug." If you're happy with "not the right word" by all means use *succinct* when you mean *pithy*.

Comment: The ironic fact is that ['pith'y fruit](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2a/Zitronatszitrone.jpg/1280px-Zitronatszitrone.jpg) has less of what you might call substance.

Comment: *Good* is a good word. Too bad it kinda sounds like *rude*. *Mother* is a good word. Too bad it sounds kinda like *brother*. *Shoelaces* is a good word. Too bad it kinda sounds like *Schoah racists*. What the actual duck are you even on about.