# A verb for 'talking about something very briefly and roughly'?

Tags: single-word-requests

> In the end I **very briefly and roughly talk about** the implication of
>   my view for that field of study.

What verb can I use instead of *[talk] very briefly and roughly*? I thought of *outline* but I am not sure if that is good when we talk about *implication*.

Comment: Maybe 'touch upon' ?

Comment: Perhaps 'just mention' is sufficient?

Comment: You can *sketch* the implications that you foresee. You can *briefly elaborate*, which most listeners will interpret as a shorter and “rougher” version of a full elaboration. You can *offer a prospect* or even *take a look into the crystal ball*. It depends on your audience. At this point in a presentation, it’s often appropriate to change the tone, i.e. to separate the speculation from the hard factual matter that preceded it.

Comment: @GlobalCharm Yes, or I **sketched out** the implication..."

Answer (score 2):

The use of *roughly* is somewhat subjective, but I would use [**summarize**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/summarize):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> *transitive verb*
> : to tell in or reduce to a summary
>
> *intransitive verb*
> : to make a summary
>
> [*summary*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/summary)
> **1** : COMPREHENSIVE
> *especially* : covering the main points succinctly
> **2 a** : done without delay or formality : quickly executed
> // a *summary* dismissal
> **2 b** : of, relating to, or using a summary proceeding
> // a *summary* trial

So, the example sentence would become:

> In the end, I *summarize* the implication of my view for that field of study.

---

In a paper or book, a *summary* is used at the end to sum up what you've said. It can include everything you've said, or only a certain component—such as the implications of a thesis. It depends on what you're emphasizing.

This is in contrast to an *outline*, which almost always only comes before something about to be discussed in detail.

Comment: Is 'summarize' commonly used for implication?

Comment: Yes, and I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Touch upon** seems to fit...

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/touch%20on%2Fupon

> to briefly talk or write about (something) : to mention (something) briefly
>
> “The reports touched on many important points.”
>
> “She touches upon the issue in the article but never fully explains it.”

In your example:

> In the end I **touch upon** the implication of my view for that field of study.

Comment: Ah, I should have read the comments on the original question - “touch on” is already mentioned there. It’s here as an answer as well now anyway...

Answer (score 1):

The choice is very wide.  You could search a thesaurus and pick what seems to you suitable from that.  It does not have to be a word for 'talk'.  So you have been offered *touch upon*, which would do fine as a familiar metaphorical expression.  In that vein, you could '*sketch* (or *shade*) *in*'; or '*outline*'.

I notice, however, that you use the singular "*implication*".  If there is only one implication, would it be anything other than brief?

Comment: Interesting, I would have used the phrasing "sketch out" instead of "sketch in" (but I agree with "shade in").

Comment: Sketch out or sketch in?

Answer (score -2):

The word **succinct** seems a perfect fit.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/succinct

Comment: OP asks for a verb.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh, missed that totally. But I could still think of ways to tweak the sentence into using this adjective.

Comment: Yes, but it's not really of the standard ELU requires, more ELL. Please have a look at some of the more heavily upvoted grammar questions/answers here; 'What's a good word for' questions can be good, but here no research is done (eg looking up synonyms for 'outline', 'brief'). Not very scholarly.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh, but I hope that as long as the sentence doesn't violate any grammatical rules, it's fine. Nonetheless, I would love to hear if you have any suggestions for this question.

Comment: OP specifies quite precisely (twice) what they want and gives a suggestion they feel inadequate. I gave one over a year ago. / Suggesting rewrites is _not_ exactly on-topic on ELU. And 'succinct' has already been given at [how to say 'short, sweet, to-the point in one word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/356785/how-to-say-short-sweet-to-the-point-in-one-word/356794#356794) (and probably in many other threads).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth eh, then can you at least link to your answer?

Comment: I felt it was only worthy of 'comment' status on a site aimed at linguists. The second comment under the question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh well.